# permutations on number of ways boys and girls sit together

Tags: combinatorics

What is the difference between :-

1. $5$ boys and $5$ girls need to sit in a row so that no two boys should sit together
2. $5$ boys and $5$ girls should sit in a row alternatively ?

Comment: condition $2$ is a $subset$ of possibilities of condition $1$.

Comment: *Alternatively* is incorrect; the correct word here is *alternately*.

Comment: Yea Mr.Brian M.Scott sorry for the spelling mistake.

Answer (score 1):

BGBGBGBGGB is allowed for the first one but not for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

At the first one you are looking just at the **boys**, you need to verify that there are no two boys siting together.
What about the girls? you don't mind...

At the second part you have to make sure that all the **boys** *and* the **girls** are not siting together...

Hope it's clear :-)